# inData.open and inData.close in C++

Tags: c++

I found the properly way to add a while so I can complete this exercise. However, there are 2 things that require a touch. The file output is displaying twice. The first time properly, and the second time in a single line ( I don't need this line to show up). The second issue is the account ++ function. It has to display the counting  of 7 words but it's counting  8 instead. Why? could you help me with this. the issue is in the last while.

```
 #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>//step#1
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;
    int main()

    {

        string word, fileName;
        int charcounter = 0, wordcounter = 0;
        char character;

        ifstream inData;// incoming file stream variable

        cout << " Enter filename or type quit to exit: ";
        cin >> fileName;



        //loop to allow for multiple files data reads
        while (fileName != "quit")

        {
            inData.open(fileName.c_str());//open file and bind file to ifstream variable

        //loop for file not found validation
            while (!inData)//filestream is in fail state due to no file
            {
                inData.clear();//clear the fail state 
                cout << "File not found. Enter the correct filename: ";
                cin >> fileName;
                inData.open(fileName.c_str());
            }


            inData >> character;//extract a single character from the file
            cout << "\n*****************************\n";
            while (inData)


            {
                cout << character;
                inData.get(character);//extract the next character and the next character
                charcounter++;

            }
    //Here is the loop that is missing something
    //I was told to close the file 

            inData.close();

    //open up the file again and add the while loop

            inData.open(fileName.c_str());

            while (inData)

            {

                cout << word;
                inData >> word;//extract the next word and the next word
                wordcounter++;
            }



            cout << "\n******************************\n";
            cout << fileName << " has " << wordcounter << " words" << endl;
            inData.close();//close the ifstream conection to the data file


            charcounter = 0; //reset char and word counts
            wordcounter = 0;
                //port for next file or exit
            cout << "Enter a filename or type quit to exit: ";
            cin >> fileName;

        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: You have the same issue in your loops as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting redundant output is you are outputting the contents of the file *twice*, e.g.

**lines 39 - 43**

```
        while (inData)


        {
            cout << character;
            ...
```

**lines 57 - 61**

```
        while (inData)

        {

            cout << word;
            ...
```

Whether you output *character-by-character*, or *word-by-word*, you are outputting the contents of the file. Doing it once *character-by-character* in one loop and then doing it again *word-by-word* in another results in twice the output.

Further, there is no need to loop over the file twice to count the characters and then words -- do it all in a single loop, e.g.

```
        int charcounter = 0,
            wordcounter = 0,
            inword = 0;         /* flag indicating reading chars in word */
        ...
        while (inData.get(character)) { /* read each character in file */
            if (isspace (character))    /* if character is whitespace */
                inword = 0;             /* set inword flag zero */
            else {                      /* if non-whitespace */
                if (!inword)            /* if not already in word */
                    wordcounter++;      /* increment wordcounter */
                inword = 1;             /* set inword flag 1 */
            }
            charcounter++;              /* increment charcounter */
        }
```

The remaining problems you have are just due to the jumbled loop logic you try and employ to be able to open different files until the user types `"quit"`. You only need one outer-loop that will loop continually until the user types `"quit"`. You don't need multiple checks and multiple prompts for the filename. Simply use a single loop, e.g.

```
    for (;;) {      /* loop continually until "quit" entered as fileName */
        string word, fileName;  /* fileName, character, inData are */
        char character;         /* only needed within loop */
        int charcounter = 0,
            wordcounter = 0,
            inword = 0;         /* flag indicating reading chars in word */
        ifstream inData;

        cout << "\nEnter filename or type quit to exit: ";
        if (!(cin >> fileName)) {       /* validate every read */
            cerr << "(error: fileName)\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (fileName == "quit")         /* test for quit */
            return 0;

        inData.open (fileName);         /* no need for .c_str() */
        if (!inData.is_open()) {        /* validate file is open */
            cerr << "error: unable to open " << fileName << '\n';
            continue;
        }
        ...  /* the read loop goes here */
        inData.close();   /* closing is fine, but will close at loop end */

        cout << '\n' << fileName << " has " << wordcounter << " words and " 
            << charcounter << " characters\n";
    }
```

Making those changes cleans up your program flow and makes the loop logic straight-forward. Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    for (;;) {      /* loop continually until "quit" entered as fileName */
        string word, fileName;  /* fileName, character, inData are */
        char character;         /* only needed within loop */
        int charcounter = 0,
            wordcounter = 0,
            inword = 0;         /* flag indicating reading chars in word */
        ifstream inData;

        cout << "\nEnter filename or type quit to exit: ";
        if (!(cin >> fileName)) {       /* validate every read */
            cerr << "(error: fileName)\n";
            return 1;
        }
        if (fileName == "quit")         /* test for quit */
            return 0;

        inData.open (fileName);         /* no need for .c_str() */
        if (!inData.is_open()) {        /* validate file is open */
            cerr << "error: unable to open " << fileName << '\n';
            continue;
        }

        while (inData.get(character)) { /* read each character in file */
            if (isspace (character))    /* if character is whitespace */
                inword = 0;             /* set inword flag zero */
            else {                      /* if non-whitespace */
                if (!inword)            /* if not already in word */
                    wordcounter++;      /* increment wordcounter */
                inword = 1;             /* set inword flag 1 */
            }
            charcounter++;              /* increment charcounter */
        }
        inData.close();   /* closing is fine, but will close at loop end */

        cout << '\n' << fileName << " has " << wordcounter << " words and " 
            << charcounter << " characters\n";
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/char_word_count

Enter filename or type quit to exit: ../dat/captnjack.txt

../dat/captnjack.txt has 16 words and 76 characters

Enter filename or type quit to exit: quit
```

**Confirmation with `wc`**

```
$ wc ../dat/captnjack.txt
 4 16 76 ../dat/captnjack.txt
```

Look things over and let me know if you have additional questions.